# Replace a path in many text files in linux

Tags: linux

Please help me replace the path in multiple text files in a one-liner.

Suppose I have   `/home/shyam/Raghav/2014/12_dec/31122014/` in my text files and I want it to be replaced with `/home/shyam/Raghav/12_dec/31122014`, how can I do it?

Comment: To clarify, you have that string in some number of text files and want to just replace it with the shorter version?

Answer (score 1):

In a shell

```
cat original_file_prefix.* | sed 's/[" ]//g' > new_file_name
```

Or open up your files in vim and type the following (you'll have to run it on all though)

```
:%s/[" ]//g
```

That should get rid of the quotes and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this command:

```
sed -i 's/\/home\/shyam\/Raghav\/2014\/12_dec\/31122014\//\/home\/shyam\/Raghav\/12_dec\/31122014/g' files*
```

`-i` option edit files in place.

Replace `files*` with your desired search pattern.

Note that this replace `/home/shyam/Raghav/2014/12_dec/31122014/` with `/home/shyam/Raghav/12_dec/31122014` as you suggest. Without final `/` on the result. If you want it, replace `/g` with `\//g` at the end of the command.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's:/home/shyam/Raghav/2014/12_dec/31122014/:/home/shyam/Raghav/12_dec/31122014:g' files*.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

To change all the paths in multiple text files, I'd recommend to open all those files in a split window. i.e
 'vim -o [file1] [file2] [file3] ...'
You will now see all the files are opened in a seperate ViM buffers.
Now, to replace the reuired text in ALL of the buffers, you can issue:
':windo %s/[SEARCH_PATTERN]/[REPLACE_PATTERN]/g'
And that should issue text substitution command in ALL of the buffers.

Your command should be then:
:windo %s/\/home\/shyam\/Raghav\/2014\/12_dec\/31122014\//\/home\/shyam\/Raghav\/12_dec\/31122014'

Hope it helps.